# Meaning of "bareback"

Tags: vocabulary, slang, canadian-english

I've been watching Guy Maddin's 2007 *My Winnipeg* and there's a sentence there I have difficulty understanding. The narrator is talking about the coldest month, January, and it goes something like this:

> The deepest part of the winter. No end in sight. ***The condoms come off. These are the bareback months of Winnipeg.*** Your breath freezes in front of your face and falls to your feet with a tinkle.

I assume the first sentence refers to the idea that when it's cold penises tend to "shrink" (or is it just me?). But what does the "bareback month" mean here?

Comment: [**Bareback**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/bareback): relating to or denoting sexual intercourse that is performed without a condom.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Well, OK. I still do not get the "message" here. Is it sth like "It is winter. We stop using condoms and have unprotected sex"? (Why?)

Comment: I don't know the hidden message.

Comment: Both your and LPH's suggestions are possibilities. Perhaps the writer had both interpretations in mind. But I think that the only way to be sure is to somehow access the author's intentions. Otherwise, POB.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Can the "condom" part be a clue as to which interpretation is more correct, so to speak? If they "come off" = "are disposed of" -> the Soul's interpretation seems more exact (Winnipegers wanting to have some fun/improve the birth rate stats). If they "come off" = "slide off of small penises" -> it might be an image conveying the feeling of despair/hopelessness of the coldest month. Seems legit at all?

Comment: You are probably better asking this on Literature, where they may discuss probable interpretations. They will consider the whole tone of the passage (they might even have someone who knows/knew the author). We don't offer '70% probable' answers here. So though I disagree with LPH's probability estimate, I won't put that in an 'answer'.

Comment: I think the reference is more likely concerning unprotected recreational sex rather than penises being smaller because it is colder. That may be anatomically correct during the flaccid stage. I don’t think it is anatomically correct in the erect stage.

Comment: @DeanF. But is the erect state possible in such weather conditions [thinking emoji]. But sure, I can see your point.

Comment: This metaphor is anyway farfetched, plain bad taste: who will, anywhere in the World, specially in Winnipeg in January, where the average high temperature is not over - 10 °C (-18 °F), have the idea or drive to expose themselves to a cold environment for the sake of sex, considering that it is pleasure they seek and that it is so easy to  get  to accomodations that will make everythuing perfect? Are there so many fanatics of camping out in freezing weather?

Comment: @LPH Them Winnepegers seem like a curious lot.

Comment: @LPH - The Winnipeggers are not exposing themselves to the extreme weather. They are exposing themselves to each other because they have to stay indoors due to the extreme weather.

Comment: @JulesCocovin Or the writer unjustly makes them such a lot!

Comment: @JulesCocovin - You would be surprised. Plus, it’s a great way to stay warm. The Inuits and the Eskimos have been doing it for millennia. The point of the analogy though was to say that everyone is trapped indoors (where temperature will not degrade performance).

Comment: @DeanF. I see, but as it is said, one gets the impression there is in the population a substantial experience of the unfavourable effects of the cold on sexual intercourse.

Comment: Maybe my confusion stems from a sort of a cultural gap. If trapped inside, as in the COVID-19 lockdown, I make sure my supply of condoms is secure and the items in question stay ON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase in question definitely have a sexual connotation. But not for vulgarity’s sake.

Bareback can refer to riding any animal without some covering or apparatus between it and the rider. But, it also, generically, means having ones back exposed or uncovered. A woman wearing a backless dress in an environment where it would not be appropriate could be considered barebacked. However, in the context of the statement in the question, it definitely means sex without a condom. Something that is considered risky.

During the extremely cold months in the US and Canada. People tend to stay inside their own homes more so than other months. With little else to do, couples find ways to entertain themselves and each other. And, since there is more time spent in close proximity, intimacy becomes the norm. Anecdotally, there is a rise in the birth rate nine months later (around the month of October, in this case).

Some people are half-facetiously predicting an increase in the birth rate for the year 2021 due to the COVID-19 pandemic. This particular author might call 2020 the bareback year.

Answer (score -3):

"Bareback" probably does not refer to sex, as [this comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/541662/meaning-of-bareback#comment1327993_541662) suggests, but instead to rodeo where "the bareback event(s)" is (are) considered to be the hardest part of rodeo.

Comment: Bareback does not just refer to rodeo. Bareback can refer to riding any animal without some covering or apparatus between it and the rider. But, it also, generically, means having ones back exposed or uncovered. A woman wearing a backless dress in an environment where it would not be appropriate could be considered barebacked. However, in the context of the statement in the question, it definitely means sex without a condom. Something that is considered risky.

Comment: @DeanF. It seems to me that there is not involved in this situation of particularly cold season any question of risk but the sole reality of  its comparative harshness, which is , moreover, something  hardly to be associated with sex.